# Converting a struct to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, struct, std

As programming becomes more complex, and the need to perform operations on struct data becomes visible. Is there a conversion method for converting a struct type into an array of its members such that:

```
struct FooDesc Foo{
    int num_Foo;
    int num_Bar;
    int GreenFoo;
};
```

can be represented by:

```
int Bar[2];
```

Or better, dynamically as:

```
vector<int> Bar;
```

The goal is to convert or re-represent the data struct as an iteratable form, without the excessive use of the assignment operator.

Comment: Why not hold an array in the struct?

Comment: `int Bar[2]` - no. `int Bar[3]` - yes.

Comment: @juanchopanza The actual implementation hosts an impressive number of members defining the properties of an item, to be written to a file. I'm afraid of creating a mess of unreadable data for my eyes. But I also want to be able to append "special" properties as well.

Comment: With `vector<int>` you will have to copy it into the vector for your "serialized" operations, and from the vector back into the structure for "normal" operations. You can cast the address of the structure into `int*`, and then use that pointer in order to perform your "serialized" operations, which will take direct effect on the structure. BTW, what do you mean by "without the excessive use of the assignment operator"? You'll have to use the same amount of assignments regardless of how you represent this structure. Your purpose here is extremely vague, to be honest.

Comment: What if you have a struct that contains members of different types?  It sounds like maybe what you're looking for is [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) which isn't automatically provided in C++.  You can define and implement a reflection interface if you want though.

Comment: @barakmanos Would you say that that is efficient? ...or rather I can cast a struct of `int` into a `vector<int>` Are you saying the data is delimited similarly?

Comment: What I'm saying is, you can't really cast into a `vector<int>`. You have to create a `vector<int>` and copy the contents of the structure into it. Also, the suggestion in the answer given by @40two is even nicer than the one that I suggested in my previous comment (cast the address of the structure to `int*`).

Comment: This looks more like a application of `std::tuple`, which ties in with variadic templates for compile time dynamic manipulation.  You may want to add a function to convert the relevant struct into a `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use unnamed `struct`s to make a hybrid `struct` where its member could be treated as an array:

```
struct  Foo {
  union {
    struct {
      int x;
      int y;
      int z;
    };
    struct {
      int array[3];
    };
  };
};
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a067c70f6673ad00)

Note however, that **unnamed `struct` comes from C11 and its not a standard C++ feature.** It is supported as an extension though by GCC as well Clang.

Comment: The union creates a pointer to a single data location for both representations? That's extremely useful!

Comment: The implementation worked without any problems. (VS2013) This solution opened the door for a `vector<int>` assignment to append all the necessary data into one dynamic array. The next task is to create a design to handle structs with variable types I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

If your structs are POD then you might consider using std::tuple instead of structs. You could then use various template facilities to work through the members of the tuple.

Here is a simple example that prints the elements of a tuple - using boost::fusion::tuple instead of the std::tuple since it has many more tuple-manipulating facilities available:

```
#include <boost/fusion/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Printer {    
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(const T &t) const {
        std::cout << t << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    boost::fusion::tuple<int, int, int, int, float> t = 
          boost::fusion::make_tuple(3, 5, 1, 9, 7.6f);

    boost::fusion::for_each(t, Printer());

    return 0;
}
```

You could include these in unions with the struct but you'd want to do some testing to ensure proper alignment agreement.

The upside is that these manipulations are very fast - most of the work is done at compile time. The down-side is that you can't use normal control structs like indexing with runtime indices - you'd have to build an abstraction layer around that as the normal `get<i>(tuple)` accessor requires that `i` be a compile time constant. Whether this is worth the complexity depends strongly on the application.

Comment: I'll have to research it's implementation a bit and get back.

Comment: What sort of things do you want to do to the members?

Comment: Just iterate through them and write a file. I suppose that I could just output the title with the data while outputting but I also wanted to append multiple struct's data to the file- with the option of dynamically storing additional "members". Edit: boring stuff: Imagine a game character.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
vector <Foo> Bar;
```

You can then add instances of your struct and then access each element as desired, using an array-like format.

See this related question for further information:

[Vector of structs initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067338/c-vector-of-structs-initialization)

Upon re-reading your question a few times, I think I mis-understood your intent and answered the "wrong question".  You can make an array of your struct as mentioned above and index it as an array, but I don't believe it is quite as simple as that to make each struct element a different element of an array. If you are looking to make an array of structs, my answer should help.  If you are looking to make each element of your struct an element of your array, 40two's answer should help you out.